# Visual SVN Server, Tortoise SVN and Windows 7 problem -

Tags: svn, apache, windows-7, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

I am running Visual SVN Server(with Apache) on a Windows 7 computer and network. After about 15-20 minutes of my first commit/update, I am unable to access the repository via Tortoise SVN.

The error message I get is:
OPTIONS of "https://jason/svn/repository1": could not connect to server (https://jason)

Restarting the Visual SVN Server service helps sometimes but fails quite often. The only sure-shot way to get it working is to restart the computer. The server - https://jason is also not accessible via the browser when I get this error

1) I tried reinstalling Windows 7, Visual SVN server and Tortoise SVN but I still keep getting this error.

2) I searched several forums but I dont seem to be able to find an answer.

Please help.

Comment: I would ask this question to the Visual SVN Server team - this is clearly an issue with their software or setup.

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed the wrong svn client, and by that I mean, are you running a 64 bit machine with the 32 bit client installed?

Answer (score 0):

- check the apache error log. It's possible that one of the modules crashed.
- check your firewall (on the server and the client), make sure it doesn't block anything
- configure your virus scanner to leave apache and your svn client alone